# Interoperability of Silverlight vs Java Applet on 32 bits / 64 bits machines

Tags: c#, silverlight, applet, java

In the perspective of write-once deploy anywhere, is it possible to make one single development for silverlight and be able to deploy without problem on both 32 bits and 64 bits users machines ?

Same question for Java applets though it seems as I can read here it's not possible: [Force java applet to run in 32-bit instead of 64-bit JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714102/force-java-applet-to-run-in-32-bit-instead-of-64-bit-jre)

Then if it is possible with Silverlight but not with java applets, just because of this constraint Java applets cannot be chosen ? Could you confirm or not this choice ?

Update: some suggests JWS/JNLP ? But don't they require admin right to install ? Applets run in browser and do not require admin right, this is important requirement for my project.

Comment: You can ignore most of that linked thread, the OP started very confused, failed to investigate the problem to any extent, and gave out information in the answer that was already out-dated (for at least 18 months it has been possible to use JWS/JNLP (that allows to specify 32/62 bit JRE) to deploy applets while they are still embedded in the web-page.

Comment: But JWS/JNLP are not applets ? They require admin right to install am I wrong ?

Comment: Too much for a comment, too different to the question to justify as an answer.  Ask that on a specific question, & I'll be happy to weigh in. But 1st, check the info. pages on [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) & [JNLP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) which provide details of relevance to your inquiry.

Comment: There are 2 questions I asked I can't see how complicated they are :)

Comment: *"I can't see how complicated they are"*  You might, if I choose to answer them. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have never come across an issue where you couldn't use the same Java code on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine. The main difference is that in the 64-bit JVM you can use more memory, but unless you need this it won't matter.  It is possible to have a bug which occurs shows only on one platform and not another, but it is still a bug even if it doesn't show up.  There is no reason a correctly written pure Java application won't run on either 32-bit or 64-bit platforms.

I can tell you that since a couple of film providers switched to silver light I have had to cancel my subscription because neither of them work on ubuntu.

Comment: When you run Eclipse 32 bits doesn't it require JVM 32 bits ? Same for 64 bits ? So how would it be different for applets ?

Comment: Eclipse uses SWT which is a JNI based library.  Applets rarely use JNI (I could be wrong) in which case you don't need to be tied to a praticular architecture.

Comment: Yes but there is a deployment issue : if I have a 32 bit applet and user has 64 bit machine with 64 JRE will it work ? With Silverlight yes.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"32 bit applet"* - unless it depends on native code like .dll or .so libs.

Comment: ... and I have never heard of an Applet which used JNI. Byte code is by its nature byte based not 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: with Silver light I would check its support for non windows systems. Java was running on 32 & 64 bit systems for nearly ten years before silverlight was released.

Comment: @Andrew: an applet is compiled and as everything compiled 32 bits or 64 bits may matter. At least I have heard some people complaining that applets in 32 bits don't work on 64 bits machine. I'd like to prove them wrong except I can't see actual proof anywhere than pure claims.

Comment: *"I can't see actual proof anywhere than pure claims."*  Acid test.  Click this link to a [properties applet that shows `sun.arch.data.model`](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=sun.arch.data.model&trusted=on&format=TSV) in both a 32 & 64 bit JRE.  It is at my site, and requires trust in order to pull up any `sun` properties.  Here is a sand-boxed variant of the same applet Jar (same bytecodes, but not digitally signed) that shows [`java.version`  & `java.vm.specification.version`](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.version%2Cjava.vm.specification.version&format=TSV).

Comment: @PeterLawrey  Thanks, I cannot say what it does on the device from which I'm communicating, which does not support Java (it is not a desk-top).  Any 32 bit result would presumably 'seal it'.